# How can I achieve click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I select a span element on the page. For the first click, I want it to link to another page. On the second click, I want it to return to the original page.

For example, I have a link with `example.com`, which is the original. When this element "abcd" is clicked I want it to link to `example.com/ar`, and when it's clicked again I want it to go back to `example.com`.

```
document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', function() {
  a.href="example.com";
})
```

How do I complete this using the above?

Comment: change the `href` according to what it currently is .... by the way, what is `a` in your code?

Comment: So there are two elements? The clickable `span` and the target `a`? Also, on the third click, should it go back to `example.com/ar`, basically a toggle, or would it still be `example.com`?

Comment: `document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', function() {
a.href= a.href === "example.com/ar" ? "example.com" : "example.com/ar"; });`

Comment: maybe you can check the url with [window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) and filter your url to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let count = 0;
document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', function () {
  count++;
 document.querySelector('a').href = "http://example.com";
  if (count == 1) {
    document.querySelector('a').href = "http://example.com/ar";
  } else {
     document.querySelector('a').href = "http://example.com";
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
<span class="arb">Click Me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get link and change her after click

```
document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', toogle)

function toogle(){
if( document.querySelector('span.arb').href === "domain.com"){
document.querySelector('span.arb').href = "domain.com/link"
} else if (document.querySelector('span.arb').href === "domain.com/link"){
document.querySelector('span.arb').href = "domain.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold the link in a data attribute and use that to toggle.

```js
document.querySelector("[data-toggleHref]").addEventListener("click", function(){
  //Get the link element
  var a = document.querySelector("a");
  var current =  a;
  //Log to demontrate only
  console.log(this.dataset.togglehref);
  //Update the link
  a.href = this.dataset.togglehref;
  //Set the data attribute for toggle
  this.dataset.togglehref = current;
});
```

```html
<a href="/pagea.html" id="target">Link</a>
<span data-toggleHref="/pageb.html">Click Me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(a.href == "example.com") {
     a.href="example.com/ar"; 
  } else {
     a.href="example.com"; 
  }
})
```

or a shorter answer using ternary operator:

```
document.querySelector('span.arb').addEventListener('click', function() {
  a.href = a.href == "example.com" ? "example.com/ar" : "example.com";
})
```